# Jquery, animation after another

Tags: jquery, animation, callback

I'm new here and for some reason my simple Jquery code isn't working. I just started using the LetterFX Jquery pluging and I'm trying to create a simple animation on my front page. Here's what the code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".brand-heading").letterfx({"fx":"swirl"}, function(){
                   $(".intro-text").letterfx({"fx":"swirl"});
         });
});
```

The code works on brand heading, but nothing happens on intro text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a function as callback directly as a parameter. I have read the letterfx documentation and found out, there is an `onLetterComplete` or an `onElementComplete` option.

So you can try following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".brand-heading").letterfx({
        "fx":"swirl",
        "onElementComplete": function(){
            $(".intro-text").letterfx({
                "fx":"swirl"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `.promise().done()`:

```
 $(".brand-heading").letterfx({"fx":"swirl"}).promise().done(function(){
     $(".intro-text").letterfx({"fx":"swirl"});
 });
```